# Opening an image in the iOS Edit Screen

Tags: ios, ios7, ios8, ios7.1

Is there a way to send an image to the iOS Edit Photo screen in order to edit the image and return the image to your app?

Comment: If you are using [UIImagePickerController](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uiimagepickercontroller_class/index.html) you can use the `allowsEditing` property. Set it to yes an after pick a photo it will show the image editor.

Comment: Firstly,thanks for your answer. I know that but i have a list of images from ALAsset and i want to be able to send each image in the iOS Photo Editor and after editing to return my image in the current VC.

Comment: Well they you are out of luck. There is no iOS photo editor, there is just the photo.app and as far is I know you can't let it open you app.